# Do I need to save my old project after I change the version name?

Tags: android, android-studio, versioning

I am working alone using Android Studio to make an android application, and I am completely new to the idea of versionName, and while I understand the principle of it, I do not know how it is used in developing.

My questions are:

1: While i'm developing my app does it make sense to increment my versionName?

2: If I change the versionName and make some changes to my project will Android Studio automatically save the old project's information under the old versionName, so that I can revert back to that if I don't like my changes?

3: When I have released an app, in for example Google Play, and I update the app with a new versionName do I need to save the old app version myself?  If so, what is the best practice for saving older versions of your apps?

Comment: version name is only related to google play and released app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I normally increment the version number before I do a new release to publish. I usually use the format of x.x.x (major.minor.bug fix). For example, if your version is 1.0.0 and you do a bug a big it, it becomes 1.0.1. If you add a new feature but the app isn't drastrically different, it becomes 1.1.0 or if it its a really big upgrade with lots of new features, fixes, enhancements etc, then upgrade the major version so it becomes 2.0.0.
2. The version name is only in reference to what is displayed to the user in the Play Store when you publish your app.

If you want to have some sort of version control for easily reverting back changes and/or to see this history, you need some sort of version control system, such as SVN (Subersion) or Git (not necessarily GitHub).

3. You didn't specifiy whether you just want to keep the previous release of the APK (the APK is the file that is given to the play store and is the installer for your app) or the source code. If its source code, then using a version control system is your best bet, you'll be able to go back to specific points in time (as long as you keep committing your changes on a regular basis), and if you tag your code then you'll be able to go to a specific release. The idea of tagging is, you take a snapshot of your development code (the trunk or head its referred to as) and tag it (snapshot it) as the version you are releasing to the play store.

If you want to just keep the APK, then I usually just copy the APK some locally or on Google Drive or something when I create a new release build to give to the play store. Although I can't fully remember but I think the play store now lets you download previous APKs that were uploaded.

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer the questions you asked which have not been answered yet.

But before, a brief explanation. Your application has a version in order to differentiate it and understand which features are implemented in the application. When you publish your application, a version is displayed, so that when you make changes, you can state which changes occurred since the last version.

1. When developing your application, you can initially create a version, I.E. 0.0.1 or 1.0.0. You don't have to change it with every little change you make within the application before actually publishing it.
2. I don't think AS will save older versions of your code.
3. When you publish an application to the Play store, you must provide an APK, which has a version. The next time you want to publish your application, because you made several changes, the newer APK will have a different version. I think your dashboard in the Play store will have all your older APKs.

You can read about [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org).